# configure qt with qt-zlib is not recognized

Tags: qt, zlib, configure

I am trying to configure qt with the built-in zlib. I run the following command:

./configure -qt-zlib

However, during the configuration, I see the following:

TIFF support ........... plugin (qt)
JPEG support ........... plugin (qt)
PNG support ............ yes (qt)
MNG support ............ plugin (qt)
zlib support ........... system

This seems to indicate that my configuration uses the system zlib despite the "-qt-zlib" option. I would like to ensure that QT uses the built-in zlib. I am configuring qt 4 on Mac OSX with the following specifications:

Build type:    macx-g++ 
Architecture:  macosx ( x86_64 )
Using framework: Cocoa

Thanks in advance for your help!
Maxime

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer!

I checked the configure script and it indeed has a condition enforcing the use of the Mac version of zlib. I commented it and now it works. The part of the script to comment is:

```
if [ "x$PLATFORM_MAC" = "xyes" ] && [ "$XPLATFORM_MINGW" != "yes" ] && [ "$XPLATFORM_SYMBIAN" != "yes" ];
then
 #On Mac we implicitly link against libz, so we never use the 3rdparty stuff.
 [ "$CFG_ZLIB" = "yes" ] && CFG_ZLIB="system"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The configure scripts forces the build to be linked on system zlib on Mac. I believe there is a good reason but i don't know which one. You can try to edit the script to build against qt-zlib.